# Django ManyToManyField admin page filter

Tags: django, sqlite

I have the following models:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(FoodDish, 
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                            blank=True,
                            null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.name}"

    def get_total_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.price

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} ordered on {self.order_date}"
```

Inside the administration page I want to see the items related to a certain order. When entering the page for a certain order however, the field that contains the ManyToManyField displays all the OrderItems in the database (with the entries that are related to the current order highlighted).

Why does the datafield in the administration page display all those entries? When I add a new OrderItem to the database it also appears in the ManyToManyField even if there should be no link to the existing order entry.

Then, is it possible to do a select before serving the admin page so I can get only those OrderItem instances that are linked to the current Order?

Edit 1:
In admin.py I have the following code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Order, OrderItem

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [
        ("Date", {"fields": ["order_date"]}),
        ("Items", {"fields": ["items"]}),
        ("Details", {"fields":["ordered", "total_price"]}),
    ]

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
admin.site.register(OrderItem)
```

Comment: can you share your view as well?

Comment: I don't generate the admin page from views.py, I am using the built-in admin generated by django. I will update the question with the contents of admin.py. It is strange, I do use the OrderItem entries in my webpages, and the behavior is as expected. It's just the admin page that shows all the OrderItem entries in the items field of Items. This happened before I customized the model that appears on the admin page too.